# display received json data to html

Tags: json

new to programming.i get my json data properly now i wanna to display it in html.
here is my php code

```
    <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}
$callback=$_GET['callback'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM demo");

$var= array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
    $var[]=$row;
    }
echo $callback."(".json_encode($var).")";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

nd here is java script & html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
fname = screen.width;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "devangpatel.host56.com/sample.php?jsonp=processResults"+"fname="+fname,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback' ,//jquery will add callback
    jsonpCallback:'processResults'//name of the callback function which server must return
    }); 
    window.processResults = function (response){
    //it must be called with response data inside server answer
    console.log(response);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>

<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

also suggest some site to learn about getting data from server (ajex.)

Comment: It comes back as a string so are you just trying to get it displayed on the page no matter what?  Here's what it'll look like on your page as-is from the server `{name:"first",age:10,lived:["Dallas","Boston"]}` - obviously with different data

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery html http://api.jquery.com/html/  to display content

suppose response as

`{
"name":"user1"
}`

you can set DIV HTML Content as

`$("#myDiv").html("hello"+response.name);`

You can also look at alternative template engine http://www.sitepoint.com/10-javascript-jquery-templates-engines/

Comment: ([{"FirstName":"devang","LastName":"patel"},{"FirstName":"chetan","LastName":"sh‌​ah"}]) this is my json response. i put $("#myDiv").html("hello"+response.FirstName); in window.processResult() still it is not working